# Restore Backup Fails - File 'Db' cannot be restored to '{...}.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following errors trying to do a restore using the restore command on a backup file I recieved from a customer.

RESTORE DATABASE SFDB FROM DISK = N'C:\Backup\Backup.bak'

Any thoughts on what I can do to correct this?  It's looking for the mdf, so can I assume that the backup file I have is an incremental backup and not the full backup and that's why it's looking for the mdf?

I am not sure if 1) they have given all the data (the entire db) or 2) I have the right data - and I can do the restore with the right T-SQL commands - I just don't know how.

Help is appreciated.

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db.mdf" failed with the operating system error 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
File 'Db' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db_log.LDF" failed with the operating system error 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
File 'DbDev_log' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db_log.LDF'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The operating system returned the error '21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting 'GetVolumeInformation' on 'D:\'.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

RESTORE FileListOnly FROM DISK = N'C:\Backup\Backup.bak' shows me the following...

```
LogicalName PhysicalName    Type    FileGroupName   Size    MaxSize FileId  CreateLSN   DropLSN UniqueId    ReadOnlyLSN ReadWriteLSN    BackupSizeInBytes   SourceBlockSize FileGroupId LogGroupGUID    DifferentialBaseLSN DifferentialBaseGUID    IsReadOnly  IsPresent   TDEThumbprint
Db  D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db.mdf  D   PRIMARY 29622272    35184372080640  1   0   0   02925462-83CC-4222-8966-53229FA25B1C    0   0   29032448    512 1   NULL    269000000146900238  735C7F0E-F63D-4AA1-AC48-505A084AC00B    0   1   NULL
Db_log  D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db_log.LDF  L   NULL    40239104    2199023255552   2   0   0   71038B04-CBC9-4E4A-93AD-4E1268859CB2    0   0   0   512 0   NULL    0   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    0   1   NULL
DbDev_filestream    D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Db  S   PRIMARY_FILESTREAM  4691012 0   65537   18000000011800001   0   627C9AAA-97BD-4991-9C8C-90C400226A9F    0   0   4784128 512 2   NULL    269000000146900238  735C7F0E-F63D-4AA1-AC48-505A084AC00B    0   1   NULL
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take another look at the output from your first command. There is an error messag in it that points you to the fix.

Look for this section:

```
Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
```

Basically, the file path on your machine doesn't match the original machine. The **MOVE** option will let you fix that.

Here is an example of the **RESTORE** command using the **MOVE** option:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2008R2] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\SQL Backups\AdventureWorks2008R2.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'AdventureWorks2008R2_Data' TO N'C:\MyNewDataLocation\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf',  
MOVE N'AdventureWorks2008R2_Log' TO N'C:\MyNewLogLocation\AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf',  
MOVE N'FileStreamDocuments2008R2' TO N'C:\MyNewFileStreamLocation\Documents2008R2',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1
GO
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer worked for me when I executed this command before the RESTORE:

```
alter database [YourDBName] 
set offline with rollback immediate
```

and this one after the RESTORE:

```
 alter database [YourDBName] 
 set online
```

Comment: It's been a year since your answer. Do you recall if you received an error message, and if so what it was?

Answer (score -1):

it can also be a problem with access rights. make sure the user is in the `sysadmin` role.