# Unable to restore database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

I am trying to restore several databases and I have no clue why some of them fail with the following error:

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The operating system returned the error '1244(The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'K:\Logs\MyDatabase.ldf'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   File 'MyDatabase_log' cannot be restored to 'K:\Logs\MyDatabase.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

This is the SQL statement that I'm using

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase]
FROM DISK = 'K:\Backups\MyDatabase_backup_2014_10_14_055006_4726051.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'MyDatabase_data' TO 'K:\Data\MyDatabase.mdf',
MOVE 'MyDatabase_log' TO 'K:\Logs\MyDatabase.ldf',
STATS = 10
```

As I said, some of them will work perfectly fine, while others will give me an error similar to the above. Unfortunately I can't find a pattern for the ones that fail / succeed.

If there was some sort of authentication issue, why does my SQL work on some but not on others? What am I missing?

LE: I had to give this user the `sysadmin` role for a completely unrelated issue. This may have also fixed this. I'll investigate and come back.

Comment: Pleae follow for solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994788/restore-database-and-change-the-location-for-mdf-
file

Comment: @user38851 What's the reasoning behind your proposal? He's getting a completely different error.

Comment: This is having same question and solution to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345563/sql-server-restore-database

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28082/restore-backup-fails-file-db-cannot-be-restored-to-mdf-use-with-mov

Comment: @aasim.abdullah I have already seen that. That's not the same issue I'm having.

Comment: Is the K: drive an unusual location for you to put a database and log?

Comment: @RLF No. Every single one of my databases uses the same pattern as above. Some work, others fail with the above error.

Comment: Have you seen this? "If the database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the database" :: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Comment: @ThomasStringer I have now. Thanks! :) It makes sense now.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working.  Glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of a different issue I had to give my login the `sysadmin` role. I haven't seen the problem I described above since then.

Yes, it may work now, but I am not happy with this solution, partially because I don't quite understand what was going on.

Later edit: As pointed out by Thomas in a comment, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)'s what's going on:

> If the database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always exists).

Answer (score 1):

I received this error because the log file (.ldf) existed in the folder that I was restoring to.

Deleting the orphan file resolved the problem.